# MySQL ORDER BY + LIMIT + OFFSET statements: how to OFFSET firts and only then sort with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table which consists of ID, NAME, PRICE and DATE columns.

I'm trying to write a pager-style navigation because there are plenty of entries in the table, so looking at the whole SELECT's output had become uncomfortable.

I've written the following request:

```
SELECT id
      , name
      , price
      , date 
  FROM mytable 
 ORDER 
    BY name asc 
 LIMIT 30 OFFSET _here's_my_offset_depending_on_the_current_position_
```

This works fine only as in the example. When I try to sort it, say, by price, it seems that MYSQL first sorts the whole table with ORDER BY and only after it makes an offset.

How do I change this behavior, in other words how do I make an offset and only than sort the resulting rows by whaterver I like?

Comment: sort on the presentation, not in sql, if you only want to sort the subresult. Of course, pager will still page by name order, which will make the result somewhat strange to use.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this ? If you want to make a pagination your query is fine, if you do what you want to do (and you have to use a subquery), your results will be very inconsistent accross your different pages....

Comment: I want to be able to sort "pagenated" output.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right, guys, it is better to sort in the php's template than in SQL

Comment: If you initially sort by name and then want to resort by price, you probably want the whole result set to sort by price.  Personally I wouldn't think sorting just the visible data by price would be very useful.  You probably want to start with offset 0 when you resort by price though, so that you start from the beginning, or find the position of an "active" row that the user is looking at and jump to that in the offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's can be easy if you use subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, name, price, date FROM mytable LIMIT 30 OFFSET _offset_
) AS page ORDER BY page.name asc
```